# Rails: form_for namespaced resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, crud, form-for

I want to set up the CRUD for users, available just for administrators of my web application.
So in routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :user
end
```

which means this:

```
admin_user_index GET    /admin/user(.:format)                  admin/user#index
                 POST   /admin/user(.:format)                  admin/user#create
  new_admin_user GET    /admin/user/new(.:format)              admin/user#new
 edit_admin_user GET    /admin/user/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/user#edit
      admin_user GET    /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#show
                 PUT    /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#update
                 DELETE /admin/user/:id(.:format)              admin/user#destroy
```

Show, index work fine but edit and new don't. I keep getting this error in the _form first line: 
**undefined method `user_path' for #<#:0x007fb6645c6378>**

which is this:

> 

How can I use form_for with a namespaced resource?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add the namespace's name as a symbol:

```
 <%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Oh man, I've been chasing my tail for about an hour until I found this answer.

Answer (score 3):

When you use form_for, it assumes that the appropriate path is [model_name]_path. You have to explicitly tell it the url with

```
form_for @user, url: admin_user_path
```