# What is the proper syntax for setting up this form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is kind of complicated. But I have namespaced routes, and this form is taking care of Customer model that is shared by two different controllers.

**my routes:**

```
namespace "self_service" do
  resources :customers
```

**my lousy attempt at instantiated an edit form**

```
= form_for [:self_service, @current_customer], action: 'update', method: :put do |f|
```

**my controller**

```
class SelfService::CustomersController < SelfService::BaseController
  layout 'self_service'

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

This instantiation does 2 things that are wrong :

1. The url for the form is `/customers/146/self_service`. But shouldn't it be the other way around? Shouldn't it be `self_service/customers/146/` ?
2. When I click submit, I get a `No route matches "/customers/146/self_service"`

**Update**

As it turns out, this.. :

```
resources :customers do
  member do
    get :self_service
```

..contradicts this :

```
  namespace "self_service" do
    resources :customers
  end
```

But what bothers me here is.. why should they contradict each other? One should be :

```
customers/:id/self_service
```

and the other is :

```
self_service/customers/:id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Routes Namespaces and form_for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853531/rails-routes-namespaces-and-form-for)

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the namespace in the form_for

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the update action, does the route change w/out it?

Comment: Hey Beerlington. no it doesn't. Even bare bones `= form_for [:self_service, @customer] do |f|`

Comment: That should definitely work, I use it all over the place in my application exactly how you have it. Stupid question, but are you editing the right view?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the namespace in the form_for. The only thing that's different from my project is that in my routes.rb i used a symbol not a string to identify the namespace. **:self_service not "self_service"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for nested resources. You dont need to specify the namespace in form_for. Try:

```
= form_for @current_customer do |f|
```

-- EDIT --

My mistake. But based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954924/285614), it seems what you are doing is correct. Could you try,

```
= form_for [:self_service, @current_customer] do |f|
```

and in your routes, use a symbol instead of a string, ie

```
namespace :self_service do
  resources :customers
end
```

Not sure if this will work, but worth a shot.

-- EDIT 2 --

Ive also setup a dummy project [here](https://github.com/azizmb/so_example) with the namespaced resource. I used the rails scaffold generator, and this is what it generated. It creates the form as required. You could follow this as an example.

Comment: Where this sets up a proper form, it goes to the wrong controller. I would like this to go to its namespaced controller instead.

Comment: It was the contradicting routes that were preventing the nested resource from working properly. So I just made one of them into a `match` statement so it specifically said what I wanted it to do. I havn't yet tried out making it a `resources` though.